# Shortcut for accessing member of an object [, of an object...]

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

Is there a short way for accessing a nested object without checking each parent object?

this will throw an exception if foo or bar is undefined:

```
var exists = (foo.bar.value !== undefined);
```

I would expect a check function like:

```
var exists = Object.exists(foo.bar.value);
```

Is there already something build-in javascript?

Comment: After reading the linked question i can say: unfortunately, the answer is no -.-

Answer (score 0):

Use typeOf

```
if (typeof myObject!= "undefined") {
   console.log('It exists')
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer OP's question : `typeof foo.bar.value` when `foo` or `bar` are undefined will still raise a ReferenceError rather than return a value that can be interpreted as an absence of value.